# Add new line between {} in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, prettier, prettier-vscode

If I write something like this:

```
  {
    factors.map((factor) => (
      <li>{factor}</li>
    ))
  }
```

I've got something like this by prettier:

```
  {factors.map((factor) => (
    <li>{factor}</li>
  ))}
```

Someone knows what rule I must add to avoid this behavior?
I'm searching but I can't find nothing useful =(

That's my current prettier config:

```
{
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "useTabs": false,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "semi": false,
    "printWidth": 120,
    "arrowParens": "avoid"
}
```

Comment: Prettier is an opinionated

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, you can see all options available [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#bracket-spacing)

Comment: This can go as a comment lol ...

Comment: where do you draw the line between what should be a comment or an answer?

Comment: Alright was just saying...

Comment: @Calfut and do you know some other code formatter that allows me to do that?